# Invalid conversion from 'const char' to 'uint8_t*'

Tags: arduino-ide

I am just a newbie, don't know how to solve this issue

```
void loop()
{
  UdpSend("Test", "192.168.0.240", 4210);
}

void UdpSend(const char* message, uint8_t * ipaddress, int port){
      Serial.println("Send message: ");
      Udp.beginPacket(ipaddress, port);
      Udp.write(message);
      Udp.endPacket();
}
```

Arduino IDE can't compile.

The error message:  ***invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]***

Trying to change with this code:

```
void UdpSend(uint8_t * message, uint8_t * ipaddress, int port){
      Serial.println("Send message: ");
      Udp.beginPacket(ipaddress, port);
      Udp.write(message);
      Udp.endPacket();
}
```

Also doesn't work, the error message: ***invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]***

Please help...

Comment: you changed the wrong one ... try changing `uint8_t * ipaddress` to `const char * ipaddress` ... then in `Udp.beginPacket((uint8_t *) ipaddress, ...`

Comment: Change the code like this:
`void UdpSend(const char * message, const char * ipaddress, int port){
      Serial.println("Send message: ");
      Udp.beginPacket((uint8_t *)ipaddress, port);
      Udp.write(message);
      Udp.endPacket();
}` Error: _invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}'_ in `**Udp.write(message);**`

Comment: `void UdpSend(const char * message, const char * ipaddress, int port){
      Serial.println("Send message: ");
      Udp.beginPacket((uint8_t *)ipaddress, port);
      Udp.write((uint8_t *)message);
      Udp.endPacket();
}` Error: _invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}'_ in `Udp.write((uint8_t *)message);`

Comment: Please help....

Comment: hmm ... ok, I probably didn't look at the code properly

Comment: what library is `Udp` from? - you actually do not need the `(uint8_t *)` **at all**

Comment: #include <WiFiUdp.h>

Comment: Remove all (uint8_t *): `void UdpSend(const char * message, const char * ipaddress, int port){
      Serial.println("Send message: ");
      Udp.beginPacket(ipaddress, port);
      Udp.write(message);
      Udp.endPacket();
}` Error: _invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}'_ in `Udp.write(message);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ESP32 Arduino package the WiFiUdp.h doesn't pull in all Print class `write` functions. As consequence the WiFiUdp class doesn't know `write(const char *str)`.

Use `Udp.print(message);` if message is a zero-terminated char array

or `Udp.write(message, size);` if message is a byte array

Comment: Wild guess that it's esp32. Props to you if you're right!!!

Comment: Juraj guess is correct, I am using ESP32

Comment: Thanks a lot Juraj, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: @JaromandaX, it was not so wild. there are not so many WiFiUdp.h (OP revealed it in comment)

Comment: I'm still impressed

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're using `uint8_t` at all

The Udp.beginPacket function signature is

```
int WiFiUDP::beginPacket(const char *host, uint16_t port)
```

No hint of uint8_t there

and .write is either

```
WiFiUDP::write(uint8_t byte)
WiFiUDP::write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size)
WiFiUDP::write(const char *str)
WiFiUDP::write(const char *buffer, size_t size)
```

So, your other attempt to use `write((uint8_t *))` is also wrong

Try this:

```
void loop()
{
  UdpSend("Test", "192.168.0.240", 4210);
}

void UdpSend(const char* message, const char * ipaddress, int port){
      Serial.println("Send message: ");
      Udp.beginPacket(ipaddress, port);
      Udp.write(message);
      Udp.endPacket();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am just a newbie, still don't know how and learning to do it in proper way. `void UdpSend(const char* message, const char * ipaddress, int port){
      Serial.println("Send message: ");
      Udp.beginPacket(ipaddress, port);
      Udp.write(message);
      Udp.endPacket();
}` Error: _invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}'_ in `Udp.write(message);`

Comment: **which line** is the error referring to - the code I posted **works**

Comment: The error referring to `Udp.write(message);` line. Error: _invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' [-fpermissive]_

Comment: you're doing something else wrong, since Udp.write can take a single `const char *` argument

Comment: Change in Loop function: `UdpSend("T", "192.168.0.240", 4210);` Also error in `Udp.write(message);` Error message: _invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' [-fpermissive]_

Comment: Previously I am using this code: `Serial.println("Send: ");
      Udp.beginPacket("192.168.0.240", 4210);
      Udp.write("TESTING FROM 240");
      Udp.endPacket();` And it works perfectly. But for simplicity, I am trying to write simple function for it`void UdpSend(const char* message, const char * ipaddress, int port)` (which doesn't work)

Comment: @wieb Provided "try" code is working on Arduino IDE 1.8.8 (if you compile it for the Arduino Uno + WiFi shield). You HAVE TO provide more details. Versions of everything (IDE, WiFi lib), setup info (board, shield if used)...